# Converting NetCDF to GeoTIFF

Tags: python, rasterio, netcdf, rioxarray

I'm having trouble using rioxarray for converting one time layer of the .nc file to a GeoTIFF. I get the following error:

> MissingSpatialDimensionError: y dimension not found. 'rio.set_spatial_dims()' or using 'rename()' to change the dimension name to 'y' can address this. Data variable: spei

[image: MissingSpatialDimensionError: y dimension not found. 'rio.set_spatial_dims()' or using 'rename()' to change the dimension name to 'y' can address this. Data variable: spei]

The nc I'm using is from https://spei.csic.es/spei_database/#map_name=spei12#map_position=1439.

My code is:

```py
import rioxarray
import xarray

nc_fo = r'./spei12.nc'
xds = xarray.open_dataset(nc_fo)
xds.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
xds.rio.set_spatial_dims("lon", "lat", inplace=True)
xds["spei"][0].rio.to_raster('test_spei.tif')
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but each operation you make on `xds` seems to remove the spatial dimension information, which you can check through `.rio._y_dim` and `.rio._x_dim`:

```
import xarray

nc_fo = r'./spei12.nc'
xds = xarray.open_dataset(nc_fo)

print(f"1) y: {xds.rio._y_dim}, x: {xds.rio._x_dim}")

xds.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)

print(f"2) y: {xds.rio._y_dim}, x: {xds.rio._x_dim}")

xds.rio.set_spatial_dims("lon", "lat", inplace=True)

print(f"3) y: {xds.rio._y_dim}, x: {xds.rio._x_dim}")

xda = xds["spei"]

print(f"4) y: {xda.rio._y_dim}, x: {xda.rio._x_dim}")

xda.rio.set_spatial_dims("lon", "lat", inplace=True)

print(f"5) y: {xda.rio._y_dim}, x: {xda.rio._x_dim}")

xda_1 = xda.isel(time=0)

print(f"6) y: {xda_1.rio._y_dim}, x: {xda_1.rio._x_dim}")

xda_1.rio.set_spatial_dims("lon", "lat", inplace=True)

print(f"7) y: {xda_1.rio._y_dim}, x: {xda_1.rio._x_dim}")

xda_1.rio.to_raster('test_spei.tif')
```

You can see that the spatial dims are lost after selecting the variable `"spei"` and selecting the first `time`:

```
1) y: None, x: None
2) y: None, x: None
3) y: lat, x: lon
4) y: None, x: None
5) y: lat, x: lon
6) y: None, x: None
7) y: lat, x: lon
```

So it's probably safest to just rename the dims:

```
import xarray

nc_fo = r'./spei12.nc'
xds = xarray.open_dataset(nc_fo)
xds.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
xds = xds.rename({"lon": "x", "lat": "y"})
xds["spei"][0].rio.to_raster('test_spei.tif')
```